# "double reverse proxy" from apache 2.4 to nginx to final destination ssl secured rocket.chat

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have two servers with webapplications behind one firewall. So only one can get natted the 80 and 443 ports.
On the second one, which does not get the ports natted, I installed rocket.chat.
The only way to secure that with ssl at the moment is via a reverse proxy.
Since I do not want the data to be sent unsecured in the internal network either, I tried to use two reverse proxies.
One from webserver1 to webserver2 and the second one from webserver2 to rocket.chat itself.
On webserver1 runs apache 2.4 and on webserver2 runs nginx 1.6.
The redirects seem two work but I do not get displayed the webpage.
If I contact webserver2 directly over 443, the webpage is displayed.

Is it even possible to use two reverse proxies? And if not, is there any other chance to encrypt the internal traffic too?

my apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName rocket-chat.blablabla.bla
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
ProxyPass / https://192.168.0.8
ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.0.8
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/xyz.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/xyz.key
</VirtualHost>
```

my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name 192.168.0.8;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance (: